# Tomcat port already used 8084

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm using tomcat with Netbeans. When I do `netstat -aon` there is no process using the port 8080 or 8084.
So I start my Java EE project using Tomcat, and it doesn't work.

```
    NetBeans: Deploying on Apache Tomcat 8.0.15.0
    profile mode: false
    debug mode: false
    force redeploy: true
Starting of Tomcat failed, the server port 8084 is already in use.
```

??? I do `netstat -aon` again, there is only my Netbeans using 8084.

Why ?

Thanks for helping

Comment: And your tomcat configuration is ...? I.e. show us you server.xml file (ideally without the comments).